# Why does my custom dataset fail in self.transform - object has no attribute 'transfrom'

Tags: python, dataset, transform, torchvision

I'm trying to create a custom dataset, but it fails in transform.

Below is my code:

```
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToPILImage(),
                                transforms.Resize((255,255)),
                                #transforms.PILToTensor()])
                                transforms.ToTensor(),
                                transforms.Normalize(mean_img,std_img)]) 





class img_dataset_fun(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, csv_file, transform):
        self.csv_file=pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.csv_file)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if torch.is_tensor(index):
            index = index.tolist()
        img_path=self.csv_file.iloc[index,1]
        image=io.imread(img_path)
        if self.transform is not None:
          image=self.transfrom(image)

      
        return image

img_dataset = img_dataset_fun(csv_file='data.csv',transform= transform)

sample = img_dataset[3]
```

When trying to run the sample, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-5dd830a096ff> in <module>()
----> 1 sample = img_dataset[3]

<ipython-input-88-682960274e67> in __getitem__(self, index)
     17         if self.transform is not None:
     
---> 18           image=self.transfrom(image)
   

AttributeError: 'img_dataset_fun' object has no attribute 'transfrom'
```

What is wrong here, any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: You misspelled `transform`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65524657/why-does-my-custom-dataset-fail-in-self-transform-object-has-no-attribute-tra#comment115845945_65524657) also:

> You misspelled `transform`

So change `transfrom` to `transform` ... and your issue might be solved.